# Python not creating a new clean instance?

Tags: python

So I'm creating a list of leaving flights in an array to iterate over in a later application.

I'm getting the information out of a long long html.

The xpathes check out and everything other is fine. I have a major wrapping object called FlightLegs. And a minor inner object called Flights.

The structure is simple. Every FlightLegs has a DATE on which the flights are leaving and THREE flights which are leaving on different TIMES ON that single DATE.

So like you have a date: 28/03/2012 and three flights which leave on : 8:10, 14:30, 20:00.

Simple enough.

So I have two nested loops. First, loops over FlightLegs. Sets DATE... then loops over the Flights in that Leg. And adds them to the array of Flights. Then ads the FlightLegs into a list. And begins a new.

Here is the code:

```
#Looping thourght the flight legs.
for flightLeg in flightLegs:

    #. is needed in the xpath so it matches items only in this flight leg.
    fleg = FlightLeg()
    fleg.Date = str(flightLeg.xpath(".//input[@name='departDate1']")[0].get('value'))
    innerFlights =  flightLeg.xpath(".//div[@class='flights_flight']")
    counter = 0
    #Getting the three flights in the flight leg leaving at 8 - 14 - 20.
    for flight in innerFlights:
        fl = Flight()
        fl.FlightPrice = str(flight.xpath(".//span[@class='flights_price']")[0].text)
        fl.FlightDepartureTime = str(flight.xpath(".//span[@class='flights_departuretime']")[0].text)
        fl.FlightArrivalTime = str(flight.xpath(".//span[@class='flights_arrivaltime']")[0].text)
        fl.FlightNumber = str(flight.xpath(".//span[@class='flights_flightnumber']")[0].text)
        fl.FlightDepAirport = str(flight.xpath(".//span[@class='flights_departureairport']")[0].text)

        fleg.Flights.append(fl)
        print "Lengts of inner flights: " + str(len(fleg.Flights))
        counter += 1
        print "Lengts of inner counter: " + str(counter)

    flightList.append(fleg)
```

Now the problem with this is that the flight legs Array in the inner flight is actually increasing over 3. Up until the last flight 600. It seems that no new object is created durring the loop... so what could cause this?

EDIT:

FlightLeg is:

```
class FlightLeg:
    Flight = []
    Date = ""
```

Flight is:

```
class Flight:
    FlightPrice = ""
    FlightDepartureTime = ""
    .
    .
    .
```

Btw.. I'm new to Python of course. I'm just learning. But now that read DSM-s comment, it might be that it is static after all. I thought variables will be public and instance by default.

How I would access them is not important. The important part is the counter. ;-)

I would access them through a foreach for example.

Comment: Exactly which line is affected? What is the output?

Comment: You don't actually show how FlightLeg.Flights is defined.  Is it possible that it's a class variable, not an instance variable, and so every FlightLeg instance shares only one Flights array?

Comment: I'm guessing all the code from the 3rd line is indented four spaces? Can you fix the indentation, please?

Comment: You are not giving enough information, please fix the indentation, delete every line that you think it's ok and replace it with comments and be more explicit with how you access FlightList, the results you get and the ones expected.

Comment: Jesus guys hang on I gonna fix it when I get home. Don't close it until then. Sheesh.

Comment: FYI, you can temporary put downvotes / close votes on hold by self-deleting a question; if you delete it yourself, you can re-open it yourself later; and you can always edit a question while it's deleted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to initialize your variables (particularly the mutable ones) inside a constructor, rather than class-global. (You can get away with setting immutable types, such as strings or tuples of strings, inside the class definition, but in most cases probably shouldn't).

That is, instead of:

```
class FlightLeg:
    Flight = []
```

...which creates only a single `Flight` list, shared by all instances of `FlightLeg`...

Do this:

```
class FlightLeg(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flight = []
```

...which creates a new `flight` list for every `FlightLeg` object.

(Using upper-case member names is not a bug, but happens to be unidiomatic in Python and contrary to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: Wow, I did not know that.